# I want to count the loops, where lists are equal and not equal

Tags: python, loops, counting

I'm trying to count the times two lists are equal and not equal, to make a percentage of times you can win the lottery.

I tried while loops, with summing +1 to a variable

```
    ticket = [1,3,4,6,7,13,12,9,20,17,'a','b','v','d','s']
    ganadores = [7,'a',6,20,13]
    my_ticket = []

    while my_ticket != ganadores:
        my_ticket = random.sample(ticket,5)
        my_ticket.sort(key = lambda v: (isinstance(v,str),v))
        ganadores.sort(key = lambda v: (isinstance(v,str),v))
        matched = 0
        no_match = 0
        if my_ticket == ganadores:
            matched += 1
            print(f"We have {matched} match.")
        else:
            no_match += 1
            print(f"{no_match} veces")
```

print(f"{no_match} so many times")
print(my_ticket)

I expect to get, the number of times the lists are not equal.

Comment: You reset `matched` and `no_match` to 0 in each loop. Do it only once before the loop!

Comment: Also, rather than sorting the lists each time, it might be worth using sets.

Comment: Also, this won't measure the percentage of times you can win the lottery.  For that, you need to play a large number of times and measure the percentage of wins as [explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_percentage).  Instead of a while loop, you would a for loop, where you ran the for loop a large number of times and counted matched and no_match.

Comment: Thank you, i didnt figure it out, that they reset in the loop .